# ng-style with 2 if and else condition

Tags: javascript, angular

Hello I'm trying to use two conditions for ng-style for angular. trip.reviewed (true/false) and trip.approval (true/false). here is my try below but I get errors. I cant find the correct format.

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': trip.approval? '#80ff80' : '#ff8080'} : {'background-color': trip.reviewed? '' : '#D3D3D3'}"
```

Comment: `[ngStyle]="{'background-color': trip.approval ? '#80ff80' : (trip.reviewed ? '#D3D3D3' : '#ff8080')}"`

Comment: Or `[style.background-color]="trip.approval ? '#80ff80' : (trip.reviewed ? '#D3D3D3' : '#ff8080')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use it:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': tripReviewed ? (tripApproval ? '#80ff80' : '#ff8080') : '#D3D3D3'}"
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmaxnt): `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmaxnt`